# Symfony 2.6: Error loading web debug toolbar only when xdebug cookie not set

Tags: symfony

Whenever I run a page on my site with the xdebug cookie set, I see the web debug toolbar just fine. However, if I disable that cookie in my browser and try to run the same page, I get the following error:

`An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found)`

How can I use the web debug toolbar without xdebug?

---

update: here's my app_dev.php file.  This works on other servers but not this one for some reason:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1', '74.80.8.75', '192.168.56.1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check ' . basename(__FILE__) . ' for more information.' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}

if (!isset($_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'])) {
    $loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
} else {
    $loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/autoload.php';
}
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
if (!isset($_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'])) {
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
}
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

---

edit2:

It actually works fine with and without the cookie on the home page route.  However, if I use a different route, for example app_dev.php/my-route/, then it only works with the XDEBUG cookie set.

Comment: Which front controller are you using?

Comment: I am using app_dev.php

Comment: I think you should try to look for your config server, it allows app_dev but not app_dev/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by PHP running out of memory. Increasing memory_limit fixed it.